# Javascript form validation

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I'm trying to make a simple form validation but it doesn't work the way I want it to. What it should do is that the border of the field should turn green/red if it's valid/invalid with the text is correct or incorrect under it.
The E-mail part is the only one which is working the way it should.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>

function emailcheck(){
    var string1=document.example.email.value
    if (string1.indexOf("@")==-1){
        document.getElementById ("result").innerHTML = "Email nicht korrekt";
        document.getElementById ("result").style.color = "#ff0000";
        document.getElementById ("emailinput").style.borderColor = "red";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById ("result").innerHTML = "Email korrekt";
        document.getElementById ("result").style.color = "#11aa55";
        document.getElementById ("emailinput").style.borderColor = "green";
        }
}
function namecheck(){
    var string2=document.example.name.value
    if /*(something that defines letters?)*/{
        document.getElementById ("result2").innerHTML = "Name nicht korrekt";
        document.getElementById ("result2").style.color = "#ff0000";
        document.getElementById ("nameinput").style.borderColor = "red";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById ("result2").innerHTML = "Name korrekt";
        document.getElementById ("result2").style.color = "#11aa55";
        document.getElementById ("nameinput").style.borderColor = "green";
        }
}
function telcheck(){
    var string3=document.example.tel.value
    if /*(something that defines numbers?)*/{
        document.getElementById ("result3").innerHTML = "Tel nicht korrekt";
        document.getElementById ("result3").style.color = "#ff0000";
        document.getElementById ("telinput").style.borderColor = "red";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById ("result3").innerHTML = "Tel korrekt";
        document.getElementById ("result3").style.color = "#11aa55";
        document.getElementById ("telinput").style.borderColor = "green";
        }
}
</script>
<center>
<form name="example"><input id="emailinput" type="text" style="border:1px solid" size="20" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" onblur="emailcheck()">
<p id="result"></p>
<input id="nameinput" type="text" style="border:1px solid" size="20" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" onblur="namecheck()">
<p id="result2"></p>
<input id="telinput" type="text" style="border:1px solid" size="20" name="tel" placeholder="Please like 123456" onblur="telcheck()">
<p id="result3"></p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you add the mark up

Comment: your `nameinput` is inside a form named `example2`, not `example`.

Comment: You might consider using CSS Stylesheets rather than inline styles like you have. CSS also has the ability to target invalid fields via the `:invalid` pseudo class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use regular expressions.

Second if must be something like this

```
var regex1 = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/; //only letters
var length = string2.length; //if this equals to 0 then user didn't type anything
if(!regex1.test(string2) || length < 1){ ... }
```

And third like this

```
var regex2 = /^\d+$/; //only numbers
if(!regex2.test(string3)){ ... }
```

For more information check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you got 2 errors in your:

```
if/*(something that defines numbers?)*/{..
```

for testing purposes, change it to

```
if (true)/*(something that defines numbers?)*/{..
```